# how to persist a json containing lists, to mysql using sprinboot java

Tags: java, mysql, json, spring, list

i am trying to post this json payload to mysql using spring boot.

```
{
    "id": 74833,
    "queueName": "NigerianQ",
    "queueStatus": "expedited",
    "dateCreated": "12/23/2004",
    "creator": "Leader",
    "agents": [{
        "name": "James Bond",
        "agentId": 100
    }],
    "OrderData": [{
        "id": 23342,
        "client_Name": 342442,
        "reference_number": 324532452,
        "queueName": "Gwarinpa",
        "call_after": "12 PM",
        "call_before": "11:00AM",
        "order_type": "CTV",
        "status": "scheduled",
        "date_created": "12 / 23 / 2004"
    }]
}
```

i have created model classes: Agents, Orders and QueueInfo to represent them in mysql. below are the classes

```
@Entity
public class Agents 
{
    @Id
    private int agentId;
    private String agentName;

    public int getAgentId() {
        return agentId;

}
public void setAgentId(int agentId) {
    this.agentId = agentId;
}
public String getAgentName() {
    return agentName;
}
public void setAgentName(String agentName) {
    this.agentName = agentName;
}
```

}

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Orders {

@Id
    private int id;
    private String queueName;
    private int reference_number;
    private String order_type;
    private String call_before;
    private String call_after;
    private String date_created;
    private String  client_Name;
    private String status;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getClient_Name() {
    return client_Name;
}
public void setClient_Name(String client_Name) {
    this.client_Name = client_Name;
}
public String getQueueName() {
    return queueName;
}
public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
    this.queueName = queueName;
}
public int getReference_number() {
    return reference_number;
}
public void setReference_number(int reference_number) {
    this.reference_number = reference_number;
}
public String getOrder_type() {
    return order_type;
}
public void setOrder_type(String order_type) {
    this.order_type = order_type;
}
public String getCall_before() {
    return call_before;
}
public void setCall_before(String call_before) {
    this.call_before = call_before;
}
public String getCall_after() {
    return call_after;
}
public void setCall_after(String call_after) {
    this.call_after = call_after;
}
public String getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}
public void setDate_created(String date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class QueueInfo 
{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String queueName;
    private String creator;
    private String date_created;
    @OneToMany
    private List <Agents> agent;
    @OneToMany
    private List <Orders> orders;
    private String queueStatus;




    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String isQueueStatus() {
        return queueStatus;
    }


    public void setQueueStatus(String queueStatus) {
        this.queueStatus = queueStatus;
    }


    public QueueInfo() {}


    public String getQueueName() {
        return queueName;
    }
    public void setQueueName(String queueName) {
        this.queueName = queueName;
    }
    public String getCreator() {
        return creator;
    }
    public void setCreator(String creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }
    public String getDate_created() {
        return date_created;
    }
    public void setDate_created(String date_created) {
        this.date_created = date_created;
    }
    public List<Agents> getAgent() {
        return agent;
    }
    public void setAgent(List<Agents> agent) {
        this.agent = agent;
    }
    public List<Orders> getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }
    public void setOrders(List<Orders> orders) {
        this.orders = orders;
    }

}
```

I created repositories for the respective models and they extend JPArepositories to enable be perform the crud operations.

```
public interface AgentsRepository extends JpaRepository<Agents, Integer>
{   

}

public interface QueueInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<QueueInfo, Integer>
{

}

public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders, Integer> {

}
```

this is my controller below

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@SpringBootApplication
@RestController

@RequestMapping("/queue/create")
    public class CsaApiApplication 
    {
    @Autowired
    private OrdersRepository Orepo;
    @Autowired
    private AgentsRepository Arepo;
    @Autowired
    private QueueInfoRepository Qrepo;



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CsaApiApplication.class, args);
    }


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createQueue(@RequestBody QueueInfo queueInfo )
    {

        Qrepo.save(queueInfo);

        return "Created";
    }

}
```

The application runs but when i hit the post method with my above json payload it doesnt persist. My database table still has null values. Can anyone help me out here.
I think my problem is the complexity of the json payload, it has lists in them. How do i handle that

Comment: Is `CsaApiApplication ` in the same package as entity and repository classes?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is due to different field names in JSON data compared to entity classes. For example you have `agentName` in entity and `name` in JSON.

These are some solutions to this

- Change either entity classes or JSON data to have matching field names
- Add additional annotations in your entity classes so that *JSON to Object mapper* is able to connect them.

For example the right JSON data to match those entity classes would be:

```
{
"id": 74833,
"queueName": "NigerianQ",
"queueStatus": "expedited",
"date_created": "12/23/2004",
"creator": "Leader",
"agent": [{
    "agentName": "James Bond",
    "agentId": 100
}],
"orders": [{
    "id": 23342,
    "client_Name": 342442,
    "reference_number": 324532452,
    "queueName": "Gwarinpa",
    "call_after": "12 PM",
    "call_before": "11:00AM",
    "order_type": "CTV",
    "status": "scheduled",
    "date_created": "12 / 23 / 2004"
}]
}
```

I have not tested POST with this JSON, but it should work....

Answer (score 0):

The field names in the JSON and the JSON model has to match with the java domain objects and java object model to automatically get converted to java objects by the frameworks,  And it is always recommended to use `Singular Noun`s for class names. E.g `Order`, `User` etc...